# How can I group data based on range of values in specific column

Tags: python-2.7, append, range, grouping, multiple-columns

So we know, if we have data like

```
[ 2,4,5,8,34,75,23,79,23, ...]
```

we can use

```
for i in data:
    if 0 < i < 20:
        data_0_20.append(i)
```

what if I want to group from the value in the specific column like

```
df = [ id, v1, v2, v3
        1, 12, 32, 23
        2, 65, 45, 22
        3, 55, 34, 76
        4, 33, 53, 21
        5, 34, 87, 19
        6, 23, 56, 35
         ...]
```

I want to group based on V3 column, what code can I use?

I want result like this

```
data_20_30 = [ id, v1, v2, v3
                1, 12, 32, 23
                2, 65, 45, 22
                4, 33, 53, 21
                 ...]

data_30_40 = [ id, v1, v2, v3
                6, 23, 56, 35
                 ...]
```

Comment: Using pandas and numpy seems to be the thing to do here.

Comment: @Evert I try but i can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it now

```
df = pd.Dataframe(df)
data_20_30= (df[(20 < df.v3) & (df.v3 <= 30 )])
data_30_40= (df[(30 < df.v3) & (df.v3 <= 40 )])
```

Comment: Nice. Logically, you'd wrap things in a loop and make `data` e.g. a dictionary with the range as key (e.g., the tuple `(20, 30)` and so). But that's just how you like thing.

Comment: Note btw, that you can accept your own answer, since it has solved your problem (and can help future visitors).

Comment: @Evert I'm a newbie in python programming, please advise.